# Submit form not allowed if tag empty

Tags: ng-tags-input

I have form with ngTagsInput field that I submit on button click.

But if user press space a few times and text value looks like `text: "    "` then I am not allowed to submit my form because `formName.$valid` is `false`. Is there any way to allow that to happen with ngTagsInput API? or any other way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

It is doable with allowLeftoverText set to true.